# Windows FOrms fonts look jagged in compiled application

Tags: winforms, fonts, windows-forms-designer

This always happens to me but I'm at a loss to work out why.

Here is my designer
[image: windows forms designer]

here is the actual form[image: actual form]

look at the W in the heading on each. See how it's all jagged in the second? WHy is that?

I've tried changing AutoSizeMode to Font (I've got it off at hte moment) but it didnt seem to make any difference.

Comment: What about other software on your machine, does it render test 'nice' or jagged?

Comment: they all seem fine to me

Comment: Looks like antialiasing not being performed on your app.

Comment: Does it persist after you reboot your machine?

Comment: yes over various machines too

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: It's not something to do with ClearType is it? I wonder if it's possible to override it in an application or something.

Answer (score 0):

Is ClearType turned on?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/make-text-easier-to-read-using-cleartype

Edit: You can tune the ClearType settings (Look at the link above)